# Multishipping Redirect/Order Submit Issue

Tags: orders, error, multishipping

I'm running into an issue with multishipping not proceeding from overview to success. The site in question has quite a bit of customization, but it is working successfully on my test server... so I'm pretty stumped. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Error logs below. When the user makes it to the overview step and hits submit (to send the order) the site redirects back to the addresses page.

```
2014-07-20T07:07:26+00:00 ERR (3):
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: Mage_Static_Block_Assets_Includes' in /MAGEROOT/app/Mage.php:595
Stack trace:
0 /MAGEROOT/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(495): Mage::throwException('Invalid block t...')
1 /MAGEROOT/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('static/assets_i...', Array)
2 /MAGEROOT/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('static/assets_i...', 'assets_includes...')
3 /MAGEROOT/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('static/assets_i...', 'assets_includes...')
4 /MAGEROOT/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Elem ent), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
5 /MAGEROOT/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Elem ent))
6 /MAGEROOT/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Elem ent))
7 /MAGEROOT/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
8 /MAGEROOT/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(269): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
9 /MAGEROOT/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/MultishippingController.php(221): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout()
10 /MAGEROOT/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Checkout_MultishippingController->addressesAction()
11 /MAGEROOT/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('addresses')
12 /MAGEROOT/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http) )
13 /MAGEROOT/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
14 /MAGEROOT/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
15 /MAGEROOT/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
16 {main}
```

system.log:

```
2014-07-20T06:55:52+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: qty in /MAGEROOT/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Multishipping.php on line 218
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have declared a block, but the class cannot be found. Specifically, `app/code/<codepool>/<vendorname>/Static/Block/Assets/Includes.php` should exist and should define the class `Vendorname_Static_Block_Assets_Includes` and extend from a known Block type, like `Mage_Core_Block_Template`.
If this really is supposed to be a Magento (enterprise) core block, then I'd investigate the customizations carefully, using the official release.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the explanation. In going through the site custom page by custom page I discovered that I had mistakenly deleted the formkey block creation function in the overview.html page. So the form was calling a block with no key.

File path was app/design/frontend/[theme]/template/checkout/multishipping/overview.html

Needed to re-include getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?> immediately following the form open tag.